# Meaning of conversation

Tags: meaning-in-context

Eve told Eric "we're on a break", but Eric misunderstood it for a break time.

Eric : Maybe I'll check on her in an hour.

Paul: I don't think that's how breaks work, Eric.

Eric:  ***I've never taken more than a 30-minute break. Then it's back to work.***

I can't understand the Erics last words. How it relates with this situation?

Comment: He is misunderstanding a possible situation of vacation or break in a relationship as a break time during working hours. So he is thinking of checking on her an hour later. And when Paul commented that breaks don't work that way, Eric is saying that he takes only half hour breaks and then gets back to his work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric is saying that normally when he takes a break it is at work and after 30 minutes he goes back to work. He is relating this to his situation with Eve and saying that since they just started their break (in this case a relationship break) that break should be over in a short while like when he has a work break. However, this is misguided as a break in a relationship usually refers to a much longer or even permanent time apart.